# Stop theme's jQuery function from running

Tags: jquery

In .js file of a theme, there are the 2 events using one function:

```
$j( window ).on( 'load', function() {   
    functionName();
} );

$j( document ).ajaxComplete( function() {   
    functionName();
} );
```

I would like to stop it from executing through either functions.php or my own plugin because I already have the same functionality coded. I don't want to edit the .js file of the theme. Is it doable at all?

Comment: you can remove the loading of this js file with [wp_dequeue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script).

Comment: @Kaperto can you post your answer as an answer? Comments are for asking clarifying questions, not for posting answers. You can always flesh answers out after the fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to know how the script is being enqueued, but if it's done right, you will be able to remove that `.js` file using `wp_dequeue_script`.

#### How to correctly enqueue scripts

```
function my_register_script()
    //Registers a script to be enqueued later
    wp_register_script('script-handle', plugins_url('script.js', __FILE__));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_register_script', 10);


function my_enqueue_script(){
    //Enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script('script-handle');
}
//hook to another action
add_action('other_action', 'my_enqueue_script', 10);
```

The `wp_register_script` register the script to be used, passing a `$handle` (id) and the script `$src` (url to the script). The `wp_enqueue_script` adds that script to our page.

It can also happen that the `wp_register_script` is not used. In that case, the `$src` is passed to the `wp_enqueue_script` like this.

```
wp_enqueue_script('script-handle', plugins_url('script.js', __FILE__));
```

#### How to remove a correctly registered script

If the script is enqueued correctly, then you can remove it from your `functions.php` passing the `$handle` to `wp_dequeue_script`.

```
wp_dequeue_script('script-handle');
```

**Keep in mind** that this function should be used after the script has been enqueued, so you should check to which action the `wp_enqueue_script` is hooked and run the `wp_dequeue_script` later, hooking it to the same action but with a higher priority.

Following the same example, the `wp_enqueue_script` is hooked to an action with a `$priority` of 10, so you should hook the dequeue with a bigger priority

```
function my_dequeue_script(){
    //Removes the enqueued script
    wp_dequeue_script('script-handle');
}
//hook to another action
add_action('other_action', 'my_dequeue_script', 11);
```

Where 11 in the `add_action` function is the `$priority` (Bigger means later execution)

**Do not forget** that there may be some scripts that depends of the script you are dequeuing. If thats the case, those scripts won't load.

Comment: The issue is that there are more functions used in this .js file. Trying to address the whole file will stop them as well.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk please clarify that on the question. It's going to be tricky if you can't dequeue the whole script. I think it is more a question of JS that WordPress. I would say it is completely WordPress unrelated.

Comment: You are right, your answer does indeed solve the case when the script is properly enqueued and the js file does just one specific thing. I will mark it as an answer and see if I can find a jQuery solution or get the developer to enqueue the relevant code separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to remove one of the event listener. For this you could use **wp_enqueue_script** hook. Because most of the wordpress plugin and template files loads here. So add a inline javascript code to after jquery load.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'unbind_js_event' );
function unbind_js_event() {
    $script = "
        $j( document ).ready( function() {
            $j( document ).unbind( 'ajaxComplete' );
            $j( window ).unbind( 'load' );
        });
    ";
    wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery', $script );
}
```

Comment: `.unbind` is deprecated since 3.0, besides this would remove everything attached to these event listeners not only the function I want to remove.